# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) on

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, dependencies, pom.xml

I have encountered this error while running my test suite through Jenkins build plan.
I have been trying from a couple of days to resolve the following error but I am unable to resolve it.

Please help me to resolve this.

```
[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] Total time: 39:59 min

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-14T15:12:30+05:30

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] Final Memory: 52M/848M

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) on project There are test failures.

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] 

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Please refer to /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite && /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite/target/surefire/surefirebooter5853374143404513078.jar /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite/target/surefire 2023-09-14T14-32-36_140-jvmRun1 surefire3294328319357479673tmp surefire_05664606915385108067tmp

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 143

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Crashed tests:

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] com.mct.test.template.rangeDangerAreaTraceGenerator.ArtilleryTest

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Command was /bin/sh -c cd /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite && /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152/jre/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite/target/surefire/surefirebooter5853374143404513078.jar /srv/jenkins/aws_linux_agent/workspace/my-test-pipeline_develop/qa-automation-suite/target/surefire 2023-09-14T14-32-36_140-jvmRun1 surefire3294328319357479673tmp surefire_05664606915385108067tmp

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Error occurred in starting fork, check output in log

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Process Exit Code: 143

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Crashed tests:

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] com.mct.test.template.rangeDangerAreaTraceGenerator.ArtilleryTest

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:690)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:248)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1217)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1063)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:889)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] -> [Help 1]

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] 

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] 

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.273Z] [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

[2023-09-14T09:42:31.433Z] script returned exit code 1
```

**My POM.xml file**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>Test_Automation_Framework</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_Automation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Test_Automation</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=${project.build.sourceEncoding}</argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.9.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- overwrite dependency on spotbugs if you want to specify
                    the version of spotbugs -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
                        <version>4.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-attachments</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
            <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.cbismuth</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-repeat-rule</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.imalittletester</groupId>
            <artifactId>thewaiter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>2.41.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I tried the following but the issue is still happened.

mvn dependency: Changed the Junit dependencies with maven-surefire-plugin
mvn clean install -U or Right-click on "project" Go to "Maven" >> "Update"

Comment: You have test failures in your project: `M4:test (default-test) on project There are test failures.` also I recommend to upgrade maven-surefire-plugin to most recent versions (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) also versions of testng etc. are a bit out dated... please check for updates...